Sort List of Entity presents in data base by date in Spring boot
I have a Spring boot project which stores data in database. I have an entity class called Fruit family which have four attributes (userId, uuid, an enum of kind of fruit and purchase date).
I want to get each kind of fruit by purchase date descending(sorting purchase date desc).
This is example of code:
//Fruit family entity store in database by annotation
//the fruit family class have two kind of fruit

@Entity(name = "FruitFamily")
public class FruitFamilyEntity {

  @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
  private String userId;

  @Column(name = "fruitfamily_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private UUID fruitFamilyId;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "typeFruit", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private TypeFruit typeFruit;

  @Column(name = "purchase_date")
  private LocalDateTime purchaseDate;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
    LifestyleEntity that = (LifestyleEntity) o;
    return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return getClass().hashCode();
  }
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum TypeFruit {
  STONE_FRUIT("Fruit à noyau"),
  POME_FRUIT("Fruit à pepin"));

  private final String display;
}

@Getter
@Setter()
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FruitFamily {

  private String userId;

  private UUID fruitFamilyId;
  
  private TypeFruit typeFruit;

  private LocalDateTime purchaseDate;
}

public class FruitStore {

    public Map<TypeFruit, List<FruitFamily>> allFruitFamily() {
    
        FruitFamily fruit1 = new FruitFamily("1","8244f3ca-1881-44e3",STONE_FRUIT,LocalDateTime.parse("2024-05-02T16:15:54.332"))
        FruitFamily fruit2 = new FruitFamily("2","8244f3ca-1880-45e3",STONE_FRUIT,LocalDateTime.parse("2024-05-01T18:34:28.127"))
        FruitFamily fruit3 = new FruitFamily("3","8244f3ca-1882-46e3",STONE_FRUIT,LocalDateTime.parse("2024-01-28T10:04:28.187"))
        FruitFamily fruit4 = new FruitFamily("4","8244f3ca-1883-47e3",STONE_FRUIT,LocalDateTime.parse("2023-07-18T22:20:45.332"))
        FruitFamily fruit5 = new FruitFamily("5","8244f3ca-1879-48e3",POME_FRUIT,LocalDateTime.parse("2023-05-01T22:20:45.332"))
        FruitFamily fruit6 = new FruitFamily("6","8244f3ca-18767-49e3",POME_FRUIT,LocalDateTime.parse("2023-05-02T12:35:26.443"))
        FruitFamily fruit7 = new FruitFamily("7","8244f3ca-1841-42e3",POME_FRUIT,LocalDateTime.parse("2023-09-13T14:50:26.332"))
        FruitFamily fruit8 = new FruitFamily("8","8244f3ca-1823-41e3",POME_FRUIT,LocalDateTime.parse("2024-05-02T15:23:45.332"))
        
        FruitFamily arrFruit[] = {fruit1,fruit2,fruit3,fruit4,fruit5,fruit6,fruit7,fruit8};
        
        var listFruitFamily = Arrays.asList(arrFruit);
        
        EnumMap<TypeFruit, List<FruitFamily>> result = new EnumMap<>(TypeFruit.class);

        listFruitFamily.forEach(fruitFam -> {
            var listByTypeFruit = result.computeIfAbsent(fruitFam.getTypeFruit(), k -> new ArrayList<>());
            listByTypeFruit.add(fruitFam);
        });

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
        
    }

}

I want to filter my result by most recent purchase date by type of fruit
[STONE_FRUIT : 
  [
   {"userId":"1","fruitFamilyId":"8244f3ca-1881-44e3","userId":STONE_FRUIT,"purchaseDate":"2024-05-02T16:15:54.332"},
   {"userId":"2","fruitFamilyId":"8244f3ca-1881-44e3","userId":STONE_FRUIT,"purchaseDate":"2024-05-01T18:34:28.127"},
   {"userId":"3","fruitFamilyId":"8244f3ca-1881-44e3","userId":STONE_FRUIT,"purchaseDate":"2024-01-28T10:04:28.187"},
   {"userId":"4","fruitFamilyId":"8244f3ca-1881-44e3","userId":STONE_FRUIT,"purchaseDate":"2023-07-18T22:20:45.332"}
   ]
],

[POME_FRUIT : 
  [
   {"userId":"8","fruitFamilyId":"8244f3ca-1881-44e3","userId":POME_FRUIT,"purchaseDate":"2024-05-02T15:23:45.332"},
   {"userId":"7","fruitFamilyId":"8244f3ca-1881-44e3","userId":POME_FRUIT,"purchaseDate":"2023-09-13T14:50:26.3323"},
   {"userId":"6","fruitFamilyId":"8244f3ca-1881-44e3","userId":POME_FRUIT,"purchaseDate":"2023-05-02T12:35:26.443"},
   {"userId":"5","fruitFamilyId":"8244f3ca-1881-44e3","userId":POME_FRUIT,"purchaseDate":"2023-05-01T22:20:45.332"}
   ]
]

My allFruitFamily function does not filter by purchase date desc. How to get the result above?

What do you mean by filter? I don't understand what you mean when you say filter by purchase date desc.

hi @davidalayachew I want the result to be displayed by most recent purchase date

I assume you mean ordered by most recent purchase date?

When you have a “project which stores data in database”, let the database do the grouping and sorting. That’s what database are for, processing data.

If you just want your data sorted by purchase date descending, here is your problem.
listFruitFamily
   .forEach
   (
      fruitFam -> 
      {

         var listByTypeFruit = 
            result
               .computeIfAbsent
               (
                  fruitFam.getTypeFruit(), 
                  k -> new ArrayList<>()
               )
               ;

         listByTypeFruit.add(fruitFam);

         //This is the sort you were missing!
         listByTypeFruit.sort(Comparator.comparing(FruitFamily::getPurchaseDate).reversed());

        });

All you need to do is sort. I am assuming that your class FruitFamily has a method on it called getPurchaseDate(). If it does, then all you need to do is to pass in a Comparator that compares using that method, then reverse it so that you get it descending. That should solve your problem.
